# Upload mass data to Firebase

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, firebase

I am trying to upload my CSV of data to Firebase but its been throwing a strange error. I'm not as familiar with JavaScript as I would like so that might be part of the problem.

This is the data I want to upload:

```
704,STANDARD,PARC PARQUE,PR,NOT ACCEPTABLE,17.96,-66.22,"Parc Parque, PR"
704,STANDARD,SECT LANAUSSE,PR,NOT ACCEPTABLE,17.96,-66.22,"Sect Lanausse, PR"
704,STANDARD,URB EUGENE RICE,PR,NOT ACCEPTABLE,17.96,-66.22,"Urb Eugene Rice, PR"
704,STANDARD,URB GONZALEZ,PR,NOT ACCEPTABLE,17.96,-66.22,"Urb Gonzalez, PR"
```

I didn't use anything fancy to try to upload the document, this seemed like the quickest way to get everything uploaded in the style I want:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.2/firebase.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://<firebasetag>.firebaseio.com/coordinates");

    var onComplete = function(error) {
      if (error) {
        console.log('Synchronization failed: ' + error);
      } else {
        console.log('Synchronization succeeded');
      }
    };

    $("#upload").bind("click", function () {
        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv|.txt)$/;
        if (regex.test($("#fileUpload").val().toLowerCase())) {
            if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
                    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                        var cells = rows[i].split(",");
                        myFirebaseRef.set({
                            [cells[0]]: {
                                zipcodetype: cells[1],
                                city: cells[2],
                                state: cells[3],
                                locationtype: cells[4],
                                latitude: cells[5],
                                longitude: cells[6],
                                locationttext: cells[7]
                            }
                        }, onComplete);                    
                    }
                }
                reader.readAsText($("#fileUpload")[0].files[0]);
            } else {
                alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
            }
        } else {
            alert("Please upload a valid CSV file.");
        }
    });
});
</script>
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" />
<input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload" />
</div>

</body>

<html>
```

This is all that shows up in the database:

[image]

What it does is upload only one row but "Synchronization succeeded" is always printed in my console.

I want it to upload each row since my original data is about 90,000 lines long. Help?

Comment: If all `cells[0]` equals 704, what are you expecting as result???

Comment: It is only uploading one row, not the entire document. When I replace the firebase upload with a console print it prints everything. Something about how I'm handling the firebase call prevents mass upload in this code

Comment: But because you always set same item, overriding ny previous one, 704 === 704. I'm not a firebase guy, but you probably want to push it instead: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/push.html

Comment: Uh.... Omg I just realized that. Thanks for pointing that out to me. It didn't occur to me that its overriding the save with new data until the end. Do you know some sort of remedy to this? Something that says "wait until the last firebase call is complete before continuing"?

Comment: Oh. yupp. documentation. I'm a moron. Thanks though! If you want to put your comment as an answer I will mark it as best.

Comment: You are probably not a morron... Glad you have fixed it and thx for posting relevant answer. It could be really helpful for any futur reader.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking for the answer in code, this is the working model.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.2/firebase.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://<firebaseid>.firebaseio.com/coordinates");

    $("#upload").bind("click", function () {
        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv|.txt)$/;
        if (regex.test($("#fileUpload").val().toLowerCase())) {
            if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
                    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                        var cells = rows[i].split(",");
                        myFirebaseRef.push({
                            [cells[0]]: {
                                zipcodetype: cells[1],
                                city: cells[2],
                                state: cells[3],
                                locationtype: cells[4],
                                latitude: cells[5],
                                longitude: cells[6],
                                locationttext: cells[7]
                            }
                        });                    
                    }
                }
                reader.readAsText($("#fileUpload")[0].files[0]);
            } else {
                alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
            }
        } else {
            alert("Please upload a valid CSV file.");
        }
    });
});
</script>
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" />
<input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload" />
</div>

</body>

<html>
```